# Unable to push_back an object to vector

Tags: c++, vector, gsoap

Error:
We are getting below error while calling the code snippet
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Vector_alloc > >::_Myend(...) returned 0xC.

```
bool _Has_unused_capacity() const _NOEXCEPT
{   // micro-optimization for capacity() != size()
return (this->_Myend() != this->_Mylast());
}
```

Code Snippet:
            Error:
We are getting below error while calling the code snippet
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Vector_alloc > >::_Myend(...) returned 0xC.

```
bool _Has_unused_capacity() const _NOEXCEPT
{   // micro-optimization for capacity() != size()
return (this->_Myend() != this->_Mylast());
}


class  A 
{
public:
    class B *objTRANSACTIONID;
};
// second class
class  B {
public:
    std::vector<class C * >TRANSACTIONID;
};
// Third class
class C {
public:
    std::string *APPLICATIONID;
    std::string *CREATEDBY;
};
//  C++ Code
int main()
{
    A *aObject =new A();
    C *DNINFO = new C();
    std::string FieldName = "UserType";
    DNINFO->APPLICATIONID = &FieldName;
    DNINFO->CREATEDBY = &FieldName;
    // Throws error as “unused capacity” for vector.
    aObject->objTRANSACTIONID->TRANSACTIONID.push_back(DNINFO);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have pointers to `double` and `std::string` members? Are those supposed to be arrays? Otherwise it doesn't make any sense. Also don't use Unicode-characters when writing code here on stackoverflow.com, copy-paste an actual [mcve] instead.

Comment: As for your problem, might it be related to all your pointers and where they might point? Because right now it doesn't seem like you're actually making them point anywhere? Also without an [mcve] it's impossible for us to replicate the problem or tell you what the problem might really be.

Comment: Lastly, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks @Some programmer dude for your guide. We have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `A` object has an uninitialised `objTRANSACTIONID`, there is no `B` object to push `DNINFO` into it's `TRANSACTIONID`.

Don't use pointers and `new` here if you can

```
// Third class
class C {
public:
    std::string APPLICATIONID;
    std::string CREATEDBY;
};

// second class
class  B {
public:
    std::vector<C>TRANSACTIONID;
};

class  A 
{
public:
    B objTRANSACTIONID;
};


//  C++ Code
int main()
{
    A aObject;
    C DNINFO;
    std::string FieldName = "UserType";
    DNINFO->APPLICATIONID = FieldName;
    DNINFO->CREATEDBY = FieldName;
    aObject.objTRANSACTIONID.TRANSACTIONID.push_back(DNINFO);
}
```

Apparently your classes are tool-generated, so in that case you have to allocate a `B`. Note that this tool should tell you when (or if) it `delete`s things. If it doesn't, throw the tool away and write sensible classes yourself.

```
//  C++ Code
int main()
{
    A  aObject;
    aObject.objTRANSACTIONID = new B;
    C * DNINFO = new C;
    DNINFO->APPLICATIONID = new std::string("UserType"); // have to assume owning raw pointer
    DNINFO->CREATEDBY = new std::string("UserType"); // have to assume owning raw pointer
    aObject.objTRANSACTIONID->TRANSACTIONID.push_back(DNINFO);
}
```

Comment: Thanks #Caleth. Actually shared classes are generated through gSoap for a soap service. We can't remove pointers. Is there an alternate for this?

Comment: @raj I want to say change the tool, but that might not be possible, see edit